# serach oracle database using multiple fields

Tags: php, oracle

I am using this code to serach database and I am using 4 fields in this code but this code does not serach database value. 
where problem in this code tell me plz edit my code for full working serach with 4 fields
my code  :

```
       <?php
      {
     include ('connection.php');
       if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

     $optid = $_POST['OPRID'];
     $optdec = $_POST['OPRDEFNDESC'];
     $empid = $_POST['EMPLID'];
      $empmail = $_POST['EMAILID'];
       $query ="SELECT  * FROM OPERATOR WHERE OPRID LIKE '%".$optid."%'  
        or OPRDEFNDESC LIKE '%".$optdec."%' or EMPLID LIKE '%".$empid."%'
        or EMAILID LIKE '%".$empmail."%' "; 

        }
    else{
  $query="SELECT * FROM OPERATOR";
$objParse = oci_parse ($ora_conn, $query);
    }
   ?>

  <form action="multi.php" method="get" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>">
  <table width="500" border="1" align="center">  
 <tr>  
 <th>Operator ID
<input name="OPRID" type="text" id="OPRID" value="";>  
<tr>  
<th>Operator Name
 <input name="OPRDEFNDESC" type="text" id="OPRDEFNDESC" value="";>  
  <tr>  
 <th>Person ID
 <input name="EMPLID" type="text" id="EMPLID" value="";>  
 <tr>  
 <th>Email ID
 <input name="EMAILID" type="text" id="EMAILID" value="";>  
 <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>  
 </tr>  
 </table>  
  </form> 
  <table>
 <tr>
     <td>Operator ID</td>
    <td>Operator Name</td>
    <td>Person ID</td>
     <td>Email ID</td>
  </tr>
  <?  

  $success = oci_execute($objParse);
 //while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse,OCI_BOTH)) 
 while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) 

 {  

 ?>  
 <tr>  
  <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["OPRID"];?></div></td>  
  <td><?=$objResult["OPRDEFNDESC"];?></td>  
  <td><?=$objResult["EMPLID"];?></td>  
  <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["EMAILID"];?></div></td> 
  <td align="center"><a  href="Optr_Edit.php?OprID= 

  <?=$objResult["OPRID"];?>">Edit</a></td> 
  </tr>  
   <?  
    }  
    ?>  
  </table>  
  <?  
 oci_free_statement($objParse);
  oci_close($ora_conn); 
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: `oracle` tag is irrelevant here, and `dropbox` tag refers to the file-hosting service. Please fix your tags.

Comment: @pop try with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<tr>
  <td><div align="right"><strong>Password&nbsp;Encrypted:</strong></div></td>
  <td>
      <select name="txtENCRYPTED">
          <option value="">Select</option>
              <option <?php if ($objResult["ENCRYPTED"] == "Y") {echo 'selected';} ?>value="Y">Y</option>
    <option <?php if ($objResult["ENCRYPTED"] == "N") {echo 'selected';} ?> value="N">N</option>      
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: first check the $objResult["ENCRYPTED"] value

Comment: <td> <?php echo $objResult["ENCRYPTED"]?></td> if the value comes then surely my code will work perfecly

Comment: when i am not use dropbox then value come from database but when i am use dorpbox then it's show omly dropbox >>>>select<<<<

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong

Select element do not have value attribute

You have value attribute only in options element.

For eg:

```
<select name="txtENCRYPTED" id="txtENCRYPTED">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
    <option value="N">N</option>
</select>
```

Comment: an example could be better your answer

Comment: i am new in php coding plz explain

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have provided the db-retrived-data in  tags  setting .
The  tag defines the menu. It can have the following settings 
The **name** setting adds an internal name to the field so the program that handles the form can identify the fields.
The **size** option defines how many items should be visible at a time. Default is one item.
The **multiple** setting will allow for multiple selections if present.

The  tag defines the single items in the menu.
The **value** setting defines what will be submitted if the item is selected.

one solution :-

```
    <form  method="post" action="" >
    <select name="encrypt" value="encrypted" id='select'>
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="<?php if($objResult["ENCRYPTED"]=='Y'){ echo 'Y'; } ?>">Y</option>
     <option value="<?php if($objResult["ENCRYPTED"]=='N'){ echo 'N'; } ?>">N</option>     
  </select>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" id='form'/>
</form>
</td>
</tr> 

//script type jquery.js 
//script type javascript

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
       alert($('#select').val());
    });
});
</script>
```